# internet bandwidth control among programs in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet, bandwidth

I have comcast basic cable internet, i am getting 7mbps down based on speedtest.net. I am running windows 7, normal installation.

Whenever I am downloading something (via http or ftp or p2p), the downloading stream tends to use up my entire bandwidth, such that i won't even be able to browse the web in a browser. This happens when, e.g. and game update that uses p2p (league of legends, starcraft, path of exile, etc.), or downloading a game from steam, or any regular http download of a large file. When this happens, my mumble will disconnect from the server, gchat will be disconnected, can't load any web pages.

Is this normal? Is there a windows setting that controls bandwidth usage for applications in windows. I remember even in old dialup days I am able to torrent and browse the web (with slower page loading speed but not completely disconnected). Please advise and let me know what's going on.

Comment: Doesn't seem normal unless you are using an USB cable to connect to your modem/router.

Comment: Have you considered logging into your router and setting up QOS if it has the feature?

Comment: I can setup QoS to limit bandwidth on this computer -- but that's not what i am trying to do. I still want the full bandwidth to this computer, but not having p2p/http download to use all bandwidth that I can't even browse.
@DoktoroReichard my setup is pretty normal, ethernet to router to cable modem